# JTAG Bus Length

Tags: jtag, debugging

Could anyone tell me if JTAG requires to have the same bus(wire) length for TDI, TDO, TMS, and TCK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you should pay attention to the datasheet and general signal integrity issues with the signals, no, they don't have to be exactly the same length.
Many programmers allow you to slow down the clock rate if you are having issues anyway - just make sure you read the literature for whatever it is you are designing for.